# No Java for Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 10.4 in VMWare Workstation.

When I try to install java, I couldn't find the package:

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate
```

I'm confused.

Comment: Please remove VMWare from the title, as this has nothing to do with VMWare. As written it sounds like there's an issue with VMWare.  It'd also be better to reference 10.04 in the title.  So, "No Java for Ubuntu under VMWare?" would be much better written as "No Java for Ubuntu 10.04?"

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu is supporting OpenJDK-6 on Lucid Lynx (10.04).  See the [Ubuntu packages for OpenJDK](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk) for details.  See also:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JavaInstallation

As someone else mentioned, the Ubuntu/Debian multiverse repositories have additional Java packages; you can enable them by following these instructions:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: +1, OpenJDK is not much different from Sun JDK, and it has better support in Ubuntu.

Comment: OpenJDK 6 *is* Sun JDK -- with a couple of libraries swapped out because of licensing issues.  OpenJDK 7 will be the base for Sun JDK, not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. I solved the problem by uncommenting the following lines in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

Comment: BTW Linux Mint, which is based on Ubuntu, has Sun JVM bundled.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the multiverse repository component, I think.

I can't remember if it is enabled by dafault.

[here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-enable-the-universe-and-multiverse-repositories-in-ubuntu-804-hardy.html) is info to enable the multiverse for an older version, but it should be similar for 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable your `universe` and `multiverse` repositories by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`

It's not in the default sources list.

Answer (score 1):

Do a search:

```
apt-cache search java
```

See the correct JRE name. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could always download and install Java from the Sun / Java website.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your APT?

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ubuntu Software Center, to download java and many other Tools/Softwares